# My mongo db is not able to connect to my node js application

Tags: docker-compose

I am a beginner with docker and I am trying to set up a docker compose file to bring up an application and that application uses mongo db. This is my docker compose file.

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  iap:
    network_mode: host
    image: myrepo/myapp:v1
    volumes:
      - "appdata:/opt/myapp"
    ports:
      - "xxx:xxx"  # Web UI (TCP)
    depends_on:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    network_mode: host
    image: myregistry/mongo:4.2
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - mongodata:/data/db
      - "$PWD/seed-data:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/"
    command: mongod
```

when I do docker compose up, this is the error that I see
`(node:34) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongo`

I also have an entry point script

`db.auth('admin', 'admin')

db = db.getSiblingDB('pronghorn')
db.createUser({
user: 'test',
pwd: 'test',
roles: [
{
role: 'dbOwner',
db: 'test'
}
]
});
`

I do not have a lot of experience with docker and I want to know what am I doing wrong here?
Please can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Error you are getting is connectivity error, so I guess it's wrong port or host, double check that and look at [this](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo) for more info about docker mongo setup.

Try to set ports without ""

ports:

- 27017:27017

Answer (score 0):

if you use docker, at config nodejs MONGO_HOST is 'mongo' (name service)

Comment: where do I specify the db name?